# sql oracle: create a flag when a row is linked

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `positions` with following columns

```
id  linkedId
A   
B   
C   B
D   
E
```

I want to make a query where we get an extra column with a flag that represent if the id is linked somewhere. The result would look like this for my example:

```
id  linkedid    flag
A               no
B               yes
C   B           no
D               no
E               no
```

We have the flag yes in row B, because B is linked to C.

How can I have a query with the table `positions` to make this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` and `case`:

```
select p.id, p.linkedid,
       (case when exists (select 1 from positions p2 where p2.linkedid = p.id)
             then 'yes' else 'no'
        end) as flag
from positions p;
```